# what characters are allowed in a JWT token?

Tags: jwt

I saw JWT token consists of A-Z,a-Z,0-9 and special characters `-` and `_`. I want to know the list of characters that are allowed in a JWT token?

Comment: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From the [JWT introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/): “The output is three Base64-URL strings separated by dots”.

Base64 has a [number of different variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) depending on where the encoding will be used. Typical MIME base64 will use `+/` as the final two characters, but Base64-URL ([RFC 4648 §5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5)) is intended to be used in URLs and filenames, so uses `-_` instead.

Therefore a JWT will use the characters a–z, A–Z, 0–9, and `-_`, separated by `.`. Or, as a regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$
```

Depending on your flavour of regex, `\w` should match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` so you might be able to make this look a bit neater:

```
^[\w-]+\.[\w-]+\.[\w-]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Jwt introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction/) . I found that jwt token has three parts: Header, payload and signature seperated by dot(.).
and if we are using `HMAC SHA256` algorithm , the signature will be created in the following way :

```
HMACSHA256(
  base64UrlEncode(header) + "." +
  base64UrlEncode(payload),
  secret)
```

Which clearly shows that it use `base64Url` Encode format for  header and payload. 
`base64Url` encode format has the following characters and symbols used:

```
Base64Url
A     a     0
B     b     1
C     c     2
D     d     3
E     e     4
F     f     5
G     g     6
H     h     7
I     i     8
J     j     9
K     k     -(hyphen)
L     l     _(underscore)
M     m
N     n
O     o
P     p
Q     q
R     r
S     s
T     t
U     u
V     v
W     w
X     x
Y     y
Z     z
```

I hope this clears you that what symbols used for `jwt` token while using `HMAC SHA256` algorithm.

Comment: The character set that is used for JWT is not related to or dependent on the signature algorithm.