# Get unicode char from jwt in Azure API Management policy

Tags: jwt, azure-api-management, bearer-token

In Azure API management policy, it tries to get claim name from JWT. It works fine when we have normal english text. However, it fails when name contains any Unicode chars("J**ą**hn") then it fails. Following is code snippet:

```
var jwt = context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Authorization").AsJwt();                     
return jwt?.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("name") ?? "unknown";
```

Comment: JWT is base64 encoded. Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55201011/what-characters-are-allowed-in-a-jwt-token and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56222808/decrypt-bearer-token-in-azure-api-management-to-get-acr-values

Comment: Did the above reference thread resolve your problem ?